# Not able to install maven on windows

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java, windows, maven

Getting error while trying to install maven on windows.

What I have tried is, I have set the Environment variables as follows:

System variable::

```
MAVEN_HOME :: C:\Users\hari\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9
User Variable::

PATH : C:\Users\HARI\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre
ERROR in cmd::

C:\Users\hari>mvn -version
```

Error:

```
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
        org/codehaus/plexus/logging/LoggerManager

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getEnhancedMainMethod(Launcher.java:172)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:268)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.logging.LoggerManager

```
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)


    ... 10 more
```

what should I do to configure it rightly?

Comment: Which eclipse version you have installed on your windows machine?

Comment: I cannot see Java in your PATH. Is it mentioned?

Comment: Using Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is not about testing, but about software development build tools. Better asked and probably already answered on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Also installing in your download directory doesn't really look like a valid long term strategy.

Answer (score 3):

**Steps to install Maven:**

- Install JDK and add path of JAVA_HOME
- Download Apache Maven
- Add M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME
- Add To PATH

Modify your System variables:
Add both M2_HOME, JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME variables in the Windows environment, and point it to your Maven folder.

```
MAVEN_HOME :: C:\Users\hari\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9

JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
```

Take the path up to the JDK only.

Same as MAVEN_HOME add similar path of M2_HOME.

> **M2_HOME or MAVEN_HOME:**
>   Maven document said add M2_HOME only, but some programs still reference Maven folder with MAVEN_HOME, so, it’s safer to add both.

Add To PATH:

Update PATH variable, append Maven bin folder – %M2_HOME%\bin, so that you can run the Maven’s command everywhere.

Still, there is any error refer [this link.](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

MAVEN_HOME should probably be M2_HOME: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274864/cant-run-maven

As MAVEN_HOME is for Maven version 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136324/what-is-the-difference-between-m2-home-and-maven-home